# US English use of 'motivate'

Tags: verbs

In US English, is it acceptable to use the word 'motivate' in the following context?

We motivated the decisions regarding...

I believe that it is OK in South Africa but not in the UK.

Comment: No, in AmE, you can motivate people / animals / anything with free will, but not inanimate things, with the possible exception of mathematical arguments.

Comment: The ODO 'US English' entry doesn't even mention the usage you mention, whereas their 'UK English' entry at least mentions the usage as being 'South African'.

Comment: I am surprised to see this usage mentioned as specifically South-African. The phrase "motivate your answer" seems to be in use outside SA as well. I may well be influenced by the fact that in my native language, the cognate _is_ used in this way as well. I am also doubting my long-standing interpretation of "motivation letter"...

Comment: As a UK citizen, I read that as being a decision that 'someone' made, it seems implied in the sentence. And in that situation, you can motivate or influence a decision, however rather than the decision being the subject of said action, it is rather the entity making that decision. However I believe that in the form written, a decision making entity is implied

Comment: An interesting question - may I suggest that you [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/256720/edit) it to include a reference for UK/South African usage - I think that @EdwinAshworth was referring to these: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/motivate and http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/motivate.

Comment: The example given by ODO as South African, *he said he would motivate funds to upgrade the food stalls,* is definitely ***not*** standard in the US.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out exactly what you're asking. Consider the following examples (the first two from the OED with slight alterations). Which of these (if any) are the usage you're asking about? (1) *The publisher motivates the slim size of these volumes by claiming it makes them more likely to be read.* (2) *We needed funds; they said we should motivate this year.* (3) *We motivated the decision to expand our restaurant; here is the documentation.* (4) *We motivated the decision to expand our restaurant by the long lines of customers waiting to get in on Fridays and Saturdays.*

Comment: Thanks all. Peter - 1, 3 and 4 are similar to the examples in the document I am working on.

Comment: "Motivate" tends to be abused in US managementspeak.  I would not consider such uses to reflect the way normal people speak.

Answer (score 1):

No. You could say that you *prompted* the decision or that you *influenced* it.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Reubend. Perhaps you could offer some authoritative support for your conclusion?

Comment: Apologies for my lack of sources. The Oxford English Dictionary includes this definition as 2.b: "S. Afr. To propose or request (something) and provide supporting documentation; to submit facts and arguments (in support of an argument, position, request, etc.)..."


This is roughly in line with the example, where it's implied that arguments were made in support of the decision. However, the standard American usage leans toward this definition:


1.c: "trans. To provide (a person, etc.) with a motive or incentive to do something; to make (a person) motivated..."

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so; I've never seen the word used that way in US English. We don't motivate inanimate objects/ ideas; motivation is a purely emotional thing here.